# How to use a regex without raising a RuboCop warning

Tags: ruby, regex, rubocop

This is a regex pattern:

```
(@location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/) == 0
```

RuboCop suggests to use `.zero?` instead of  `== 0`. But when the regex does not match, it will return `nil`. Then `nil.zero?` will throw an "undefined method `.zero?` for `nil`" error. Any better way to do regex in ruby?

Answer (score 8):

Not every tip from rubocop is a good tip.

In Ruby 2.4 :

```
@location.match? /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/
```

By the way, do you want `/\Z/` (a line ending at the end of the string) or `/\z/` (end of the string)?

Comment: Upvoted for “Not every tip from rubocop is a good tip.” I have a config file for it that is 5 times more fat than the original one.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you run ruby 2.3.0+:

```
(@location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/)&.zero?
```

---

Also as per your specific case, you seem to want to check that you have an exact match. Hence you don't need to check that the starting position is exactly `0` at all:

```
do_something if @location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Because of anchor `\A` there are exactly two possible returns: `0` and `nil`. That said:

```
!(@location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/).nil?
```

or even

```
!!(@location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/)
```

or even better:

```
@location[/\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/]
```

Comment: Not sure why the `!` before, he just needs to check if `(@location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/)` is blank and in this case you don't need the `!`.

Comment: @TamerShlash there is no notion of “blank” in ruby. He needs to check if the `@location` matches the regexp in the very first position.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known false positive that happens because `#=~` does not adhere to the principle of duck typing, i.e. it has incompatible return value signatures.

There are some good answers already regarding how you can rewrite your code, and this is really what RuboCop is all about, but sometimes rewriting will result in code that is worse. For those cases, the generic way of marking false positives is to use a disable:

```
(@location =~ /\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/) == 0 # rubocop:disable Style/NumericPredicate
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose the following solution:

`/\A#[a-zA-Z0-9]*\Z/.match?(@location)`

This will safeguard the case when `@location` is `nil` and will make rubocop happy.